# How to remove horizontal scrollbar CSS3

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the scrollbar on this page? http://cs1.ucc.ie/~per1/

Comment: Some evidence that you have tried working on this problem would increase the likelihood that you'll receive help.

Comment: You should reformat the question to include code and ask about it in a more general way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

or

```
nav {box-sizing: border-box; }
```

because you are actually setting your nav with to 100% and add 10px padding on both side which gives you a scrollbar.